# how to get the xml in php response

Tags: php, xml, web-services

I am trying to get a response from a server with the following code:

```
<?php

$url = "http://pgtest.redserfinsa.com:2027/WebPubTransactor/TransactorWS?WSDL";

$post_string = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:web="http://webservices.serfinsa.sysdots.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:cardtransaction>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <security>{"comid":"comid","key":"$!@!@!@!@!@","comwrkstation":"comwrkstation"}</security>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <txn>MAN</txn>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <message>{"CLIENT":"9999994570392223"}
            </message>
      </web:cardtransaction>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';


$post_data = array('xml' => $post_string);
$stream_options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: text/xml' . "\r\n",
        'content' =>  http_build_query($post_data)));


$context  = stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
?>
```

However, I'm still getting empty responses, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you checked the http state (or http code)?

Comment: the status is 200 ok

my script  is able to connect to the other other server but i am not able to see any response

you can see the script in action here 

https://serfinsa.sistemasintegradosao.com/pg6.php

just make sure you open netwok in the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why your code returns empty but you can try using `curl`

**CODE:**

```
$url = "http://pgtest.redserfinsa.com:2027/WebPubTransactor/TransactorWS?WSDL";

$xml = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:web="http://webservices.serfinsa.sysdots.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <web:cardtransaction>
         <security>{"comid":"comid","key":"$!@!@!@!@!@","comwrkstation":"comwrkstation"}</security>
         <txn>MAN</txn>
         <message>{"CLIENT":"9999994570392223"}
         </message>
      </web:cardtransaction>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>';

$headers = array(
  "Content-type: text/xml",
  "Content-length: " . strlen($xml),
  "Connection: close",
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$error = curl_error($curl);


print_r($response);
print_r($error);
```

**Result:**

> Recv failure: Connection reset by peer

Comment: Thank you Darwing, this was the corect answer ! I really appreciate

Comment: Hey, @EstebanG.Gutierrez maybe you can accept the answer as the correct one! It would help Darwin in his reputation!